# Ruby: how can I copy a variable without pointing to the same object?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how can I copy a variable such that changes to the original don't affect the copy?

For example:

```
phrase1 = "Hello Jim"
phrase2 = phrase1
phrase1.gsub!("Hello","Hi")
p phrase2 #outputs "Hi Jim" - I want it to remain "Hello Jim"
```

In this example, the two variables point to the same object; I want to create a new object for the second variable but have it contain the same information initially.

Comment: [Me, stepping out of a time machine] Confusing, isn't it? Why are your strings and arrays and hashes mutable when your integers and booleans are not? Why can a method mutate the arguments passed into it? Come with me to the future, and I will show you... functional programming.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

As for copying you can do:

```
phrase2 = phrase1.dup
```

or

```
# Clone: copies singleton methods as well
phrase2 = phrase1.clone
```

You can do this as well to avoid copying at all:

```
phrase2 = phrase1.gsub("Hello","Hi")
```

Answer (score 23):

Using your example, instead of:

```
phrase2 = phrase1
```

Try:

```
phrase2 = phrase1.dup
```

Comment: Your answer works for the question I asked, which was pretty general. It doesn't seem to work for the problem I'm really trying to solve, though, which is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465696/ruby-how-can-i-copy-this-global-variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
phrase1 = "Hello Jim"
   # => "Hello Jim"

phrase2 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(phrase1))
   # => "Hello Jim"

phrase1.gsub!("Hello","Hi")
   #  => "Hi Jim" 

puts phrase2
   # "Hello Jim"

puts phrase1
   # "Hi Jim"
```

Comment: When answering, provide an explanation why your solution helps. That educates the person asking so they can understand and avoid the problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this simple way

```
phrase1 = "Hello Jim"
phrase2 = String.new(phrase1)
phrase1.gsub!("Hello","Hi")
p phrase2
```