# Ruby: how can I copy this array?

Tags: ruby

(Follow-up to my earlier question, [Ruby: how can I copy a variable without pointing to the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465569/ruby-how-can-i-copy-a-variable-without-pointing-to-the-same-object/1465608#1465608))

I'm writing a simple Ruby program to make some substitutions in an .svg file. The first step is to pull information from the file and put it in an array. In order to keep from reading the file from disk every time this function is called, I'm trying to use the memoize design pattern - use a cached result on every call after the first one.

To do this, I'm using a global variable, defined just before the function. But even though I `.dup` that variable to a local one before returning the local variable, the function that calls this one is still modifying the global variable.

Here is my actual code:

```
#memoize to keep from having to read original file on each pass
$svg_filedata_cache = [] #the global variable
def svg_filedata(filename)
    if $svg_filedata_cache.empty?
        File.open(filename, "r"){|f| $svg_filedata_cache = f.readlines}
    end
    svg_filedata_cache = $svg_filedata_cache.dup #try to copy it
    return svg_filedata_cache #SHOULD point to a different object (but doesn't)
end
```

Two questions (answer either or both):

1. Why do other functions, which take in and modify the value returned here, also affect the global variable, even though I used `.dup` to copy it?
2. I'm new to Ruby and I'm sure this isn't the most Rubyesque way to do this (and I don't like global variables, anyway). Can you suggest a better strategy?

Comment: P.S. I realize that it should really be $svg_filedata_cache[filename], to allow for function calls using different filenames, but that's not needed in this case.

Comment: BTW, the global and the returned objects have different object_id, I believe you are mentioning the strings inside the returned array, right?

Comment: @khell - yes, I based my statement on the fact that the contents of the original array were being changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modifying the duped array will not affect the original. However modifications to the strings inside the array will be visible globally because the global array and the duped array still contain references to the same strings (dup does not perform a deep copy).

So either perform a deep copy (`svg_filedata_cache = $svg_filedata_cache.map {|line| line.dup}`) or simply avoid mutating operations on the strings.

Comment: I didn't realize that every string in the array was its own object! I guess it really is true that "EVERYTHING in Ruby is an object." :)

Answer (score 7):

Enhancing the code a bit:

```
$svg_filedata_cache = [] #the global variable
def svg_filedata(filename)
    # Use ||= for memoiziation 
    $svg_filedata_cache ||= File.open(filename, "r"){|f| $svg_filedata_cache = f.readlines} 
    $svg_filedata_cache.dup #shallow copying
end
```

**Update:** a simple trick to do deep copying in general is:

```
def deep_copy(obj)
  Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj))
end
```

Comment: So ||= means "if the left side is false (empty), use the right side?"

Comment: it means assign the right side value to the left side variable only if that variable is't already set.

Answer (score 3):

The global is probably not being modified, but the elements that it and your .dup reference are changing.  To make it more canonical ruby, get rid of the global, use a class, and read the file in the `initialize` function.  (The constructor.)  Make the array be an instance variable with @v.