# Variable changing

Tags: ruby, string, variables

I wrote some code to get input from a user and then alter it to my needs. I need it in the altered and unaltered form so I am saving the input into two variables. What I don't understand is why it both variables are changing. I tried some extra puts lines to determine what the cause is but I am unable to figure it out. The code:

```
puts "Enter the full directory path of the flv files."
folder = gets.chomp
puts "Folder 1: " + folder
path = folder
path.slice!(0..6)
path.gsub!('\\', '/')
path += '/'
puts "Folder: " + folder
puts "Path: " + path
```

With input: f:\folder\subfolder\another

Output:

```
Folder 1: f:\folder\subfolder\another 
Folder: folder/subfolder/another
Path: folder/subfolder/another/
```

What I'm going for is getting a directory and keeping the directory for other processes, but also transforming it into a URL friendly format. Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465569/ruby-how-can-i-copy-a-variable-without-pointing-to-the-same-object

Comment: For future reference: http://www.arnab-deka.com/posts/2009/07/ruby-dup-vs-clone/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
path = folder # does not actually copy the object, copies the reference
path.object_id == folder.object_id # the objects are the same, see
path.slice!(0..6) # all bang methods work with the same object
```

Thus your `path` is a reference to the same object as `folder`.

To fix this, use

```
path = folder.clone
```

Comment: The other two answers use String#dup. Is there a preference or advantage to String#clone?

Comment: @thekungfuman, in this particular case - no difference at all. In general, `clone` preserves the `frozen?` status of the object and `dup` doesn't. http://danbri.org/words/2008/01/02/240

Answer (score 2):

When you do `b = a`, it's making `b` point at the same value as `a`, so when you change `a`'s value using something like `slice!`, `b` will also point to the changed value.

To avoid this, duplicate the object instead:

```
b = a.dup
```

Comment: Wow that's simple. Tested. Works. Thank you so much for the fast response.

Comment: The parenthetical comments are incorrect.  `b = a` makes `b` point to the same object as `a`, it is not a shallow copy.  `dup` and `clone` do shallow copies with subtle differences.

Comment: Fixed to remove the shallow vs deep comments.