# Constant being overridden on request in ruby/sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, variable-assignment

I don't want to copy the whole code here because it's rather bulky but here's the gist of it:

```
require 'sinatra'

SOME_DATA = get_hashes_from_db

get '/' do

 # SOME_DATA's hashes are filtered using .delete
 result = process_data SOME_DATA, request

 response.body(JSON.generate(result))
end
```

Every request, a list of hashes is filtered based on some params sent in the request. Some fields are present in SOME_DATA are used for this filter but they are stripped for when it's time for them to be sent back using .delete to erase the whole key. Example:

Before filtering:

```
{'condition' => 'rainy', 'data' => 'get an umbrella!'}
```

After filtering:

```
{'data' => 'get an umbrella!'}
```

Now the issue: Even though the original constant that's passed into the function is then diced and reassigned a dozen times, calling the .delete method on the variable that's been reassigned from the original STILL affects the original. On request 1 I'll have, say, 10 hashes with 10 fields each. On request 2 I'll have 10 hashes, but with 2-5 fields each.

I think I'm having the [same issue as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465569/ruby-how-can-i-copy-a-variable-without-pointing-to-the-same-object), however I've tried passing it with .clone hoping it'd resolve the issue but it has not.

I've encountered this particular problem before but I don't think I ever resolved it. Why does it still overwrite the original even though (in the above pseudocode) I pass `SOME_DATA.clone` to `process_data`?

Comment: I can't recreate this problem, I think you'll have to give more code, but @zed_0xff's suggestion is a good one as it will help track down where the change is occurring. I would also suggest [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to step into the code and have a look as it's running.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
SOME_DATA = get_hashes_from_db.freeze
```

now it will raise an exception when some code tries to modify `SOME_DATA`

also if `get_hashes_from_db` returns an Array or Hash then you'd need to `freeze` each array/hash element as well.