# Using string.next to assign hash values inside a loop. I can't explain the following output

Tags: ruby, string, hash, char

Program:

```
letter = "a"
chars = Hash.new

for i in 1..5
    chars[i] = letter
    puts letter
    letter.next!
end

puts chars
```

=== Output:

```
a

b

c

d

e

{1=>"f", 2=>"f", 3=>"f", 4=>"f", 5=>"f"}
```

=== Question

I don't understand why I don't get `{1=>"a" , 2=>"b" , 3=>"c", 4=>"d" , 5=>"e" }`

I included the puts statement to check that at each stage of the iteration the letter is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: how many different strings did you create in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chars[i] = letter` doesn't assign a copy of `letter` to `chars[i]`. `letter` is a reference to string `"a"` and it assigns that reference to `chars[i]`.  So after you assign `char[1] = letter`, then change `letter` with `letter.next!`, `char[1]` now refers to the same, new value of the string that `letter` does. See [Ruby: how can I copy a variable without pointing to the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465569/ruby-how-can-i-copy-a-variable-without-pointing-to-the-same-object), and change your code to:

```
for i in 1..5
    chars[i] = letter.dup   # Assign a copy of `letter` to chars[i]
    puts letter
    letter.next!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark in `letter.next!` is there to indicate potential danger: `next!`  changes the original string. All values in the hash are the same string and it changes every time.

(Almost ?) always, there is a non-exclamation mark version of the method - the "safe" version. In this case, it does not change the original string , it delivers a new string.

```
letter = "a"
chars = Hash.new

for i in 1..5
    chars[i] = letter
    puts letter
    letter = letter.next # new string !!
end

puts chars  # => {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"d", 5=>"e"}
```