# Why is append a value to an array in hash will also modify the other variable that have it assigned?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Sample code:

```
hash_of_array = { a: [] }
b = hash_of_array
c = hash_of_array

b[:a] << 1

puts b # => { a: [1] }
puts c # => { a: [1] }
```

Why do both variable have 1 in their array? I only appended it on variable `b`.

**Tried on**

- Ruby Version 2.3.1, 2.4.0
- Rbenv

Comment: [might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465569/ruby-how-can-i-copy-a-variable-without-pointing-to-the-same-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because value of `b` and value of `c` is the same object (check out [Object#`object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id)):

```
b.object_id == c.object_id
#=> true
```

Answer (score 6):

I know a person called John. Some call him Johny. Johny got shot today. Why did John also get shot?

---

```
foo = _something_
```

Simply gives the alternative name `foo` to `_something_`. It doesn't clone it or do any other shenanigans.

Comment: I have a hard time dealing with gallows humor since my brother, John, is also dead.

Comment: It doesn't look like a pointer to me, but that's acceptable answer.

Comment: @bekicot, assignment in C would work exactly the same way. Just think about it on higher level - `=` just *names* what is on the right side.

Comment: Could we maybe find an example that is more inline with Ruby's value of programmer happiness rather than killed people? Maybe John is winning the lottery instead?

Comment: @ndn I upvoted you because giving me a new mindset. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in ruby are assigned by reference with the exception of True, False, Nil and Fixnums which are handled specially.

You can test it out by looking at `object_id`

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> b = a
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):003:0> a.object_id == b.object_id
=> true
```

To create a copy of an object, use `.dup`.

```
irb(main):005:0> b = a.dup
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):006:0> a.object_id == b.object_id
=> false
```

For your example, you need a deep copy, so you can do

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))
```

So,

```
irb(main):037:0> a = {a: []}
=> {:a=>[]}
irb(main):038:0> b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
=> {:a=>[]}
irb(main):039:0> b[:a] << 1
=> [1]
irb(main):040:0> b
=> {:a=>[1]}
irb(main):041:0> a
=> {:a=>[]}
```

Comment: How would you use `dup` in the OP's example?

Comment: You'd need Rails `deep_dup`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in earlier, excellent answers, the problem you face is that a and b are the same object. Another answer (later deleted) recommended using the dup method, if a shallow copy was sufficient. Problem is that in your scenarios, a shallow copy is NOT good enough.

I propose to try the full_dup gem. This gem adds a new method, called full_dup. A full_dup does a deep copy of your objects. So given your example:

```
require 'full_dup'

hash_of_array = { a: [] }
b = hash_of_array.full_dup
c = hash_of_array.full_dup

b[:a] << 1

puts b # => { a: [1] }
puts c # => { a: [] }
```

As an aside, full_dup is no speed demon. You should use regular dup when that method is all you need.

Oops; Forgot to mention. I am the author of the full_dup gem.

Comment: It's okay to recommend your own library, but you must disclose your affiliation.

Comment: Why isn't `.dup` enough? What does `full_dup` do that makes it appropriate here? "You should use regular dup when that method is all you need." - when is that?

Comment: The dup method performs a shallow copy. The full_dup method performs a deep copy. Shallow copies are quicker than deep copies, but they're... shallow. This is all mentioned in my answer. I could add that a shallow copy makes a copy of the container object, but not its contents. A deep copy, also copies the container object, and its contents and their contents and their contents and so on for a deep as is needed. As can be expected, this takes quite a bit longer to do and should be avoided if not needed. When is it needed? You need to figure that out and exercise judgement.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, and as mentioned by [@AndreyDeineko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41722375/6419007), `b` and `c` basically are the same object.

It's not needed to exhibit the behaviour you're confused about, though.

What's important is that they hold a reference to the same array :

```
array = []

b = { b: array }
c = { c: array }

puts b == c
#=> false

puts b.object_id == c.object_id
#=> false

puts b[:b].object_id == c[:c].object_id
#=> true

b[:b] << 'test'

p b
# {:b=>["test"]}
p c
# {:c=>["test"]}
```