# why does code replace element in json array, rather than adding new element

Tags: ruby

This code reads in a json file, attempts to add a new line within the json structure, writes it back to the same file:

```
require 'json'

filepath="/tmp/my/my-apply-iam-role.assume-role.json"
user="harold"
file=File.read(filepath)

data=JSON.parse(file)

lastLine=data["Role"]["AssumeRolePolicyDocument"]["Statement"][0]["Principal"]["AWS"][-1]

# example: lastLine = "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/username.lastname"
marker=lastLine.split(":")[-1]
# this line *replaces* the last line in the json "AWS" array
# instead, I'd like to just be manipulating a string here.
lastLine[marker]="user/#{user}"

puts "New string: "
puts lastLine
puts "Existing block: "
puts JSON.dump(data)

# this line adds the new string back to the JSON structure
data["Role"]["AssumeRolePolicyDocument"]["Statement"][0]["Principal"]["AWS"] += [lastLine]

File.write(filepath, JSON.dump(data))
```

The result of this execution is 1.) replace the last line in the "AWS" array with a 'harold', 2.) add a new 'harold' line again.

How do I manipulate a plain old string in the middle of the file, rather than the entire JSON structure?

Comment: Couldn't you simply write lastLine[marker]+="user/#{user}"?

Comment: no - that lastLine[marker] replaces the text in lastLine (that matches marker) to produce a new string.  If marker="user/bob", then lastLine="arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/bob".  So, lastLine[marker]="user/#{user}" may produce "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/eddie" (if user="eddie")

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me. You have variable `marker` set to be part of the string, then you try to use that substring as the index to access the past of the whole string? ... Can you not just use `lastLine.replace!(marker, "user/#{user}"` or similar?

Comment: You use an explicit index which happens to be "occupied".  Instead use `append` or `push` or `<<` to add to the end of an array.

Comment: @radarbob, others - I guess my question is about line #9: lastLine=data["Role"]... This seems to be creating a pointer to the json data instead of creating a string that is given the value of that part of the json data.  How do I create a string that I can manipulate separate from the json data?

Comment: `aCopy = String.new(data["Role"])`.   These are different objects =>  `aCopy.equal?(data["Role"])`  is false.  [And here's a SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1465569/463206)

Answer (score 0):

```
aCopy = String.new(data["Role"]).
```

These are different objects => aCopy.equal?(data["Role"]) is false. And [here's a SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1465569/463206)

> yep that was it - thanks @radarbob –
> Jason Michael
> 1 hour ago

comment transposed as answer. (points are not pointless)